# Computing the Lie brackets of vector fields on a specific Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathcal{H}^3=\lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z>0\rbrace$ be equipped with the Riemannian metric:
\begin{equation*}
g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{z^2}
\end{equation*}
And consider the vector fields:
\begin{equation*}
A=z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \quad B=z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \quad C=z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{equation*}
I want to compute the Lie brackets $[A,B]$,$[B,C]$ and $[A,C]$ and express them as constant linear combinations of $A$,$B$ and $C$, but I can't figure out how to compute them? Should I use a test function $f$ and a point $p \in \mathcal{H}^3$ or can I do it without?

Comment: If $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism from $M$ to $N$, then $df[X,Y]=[df X,df Y]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the metric does not matter for this kind of problem, only the underlying differential structure is used.

Second, you could very well use a test function and apply the result at an arbitrary point, but it is slightly shorter without:

$$[B,C] = [z \partial_y, z \partial_y] = z \partial_y (z \partial_z) - z \partial_z (z \partial_y) = z^2 \partial_y \partial_z - z \cdot 1 \cdot \partial_y - z^2 \partial_z \partial_y = -z \partial_y = -B$$

(I have used Leibniz's rule when applying partial derivative operators and I have also used the symmetry of second order partial derivatives).

Comment: Thank you! Where does the $z \cdot 1 \cdot \partial_y$ term come from?

Comment: @Bartuc: When $\partial_z$ acts on $z \partial_y$, using Leibniz's rule we get a sum of two terms: $(\partial_z z) \partial_y + z \partial_z \partial_y$. The first term in this sum is just $1 \cdot \partial_y$, with $\cdot$ being the usual multiplication of functions or of a function and a tangent field.

Comment: Is it true that $[A,B]=0$ since the partial derivatives $\partial_x \partial_y=\partial_y \partial_x$?

Comment: @Bartuc: Yes, it is, that case is the easiest of them all.

Comment: Thank you, your help is much appreciated.